# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot detect second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have an MSI GS73VR Stealth Pro. It comes with Windows 10 and I just put Ubuntu 16.04 on it. I cannot seem to get an external monitor to work with Ubuntu. I have tried every solution I found online which has resulted in me installing and uninstalling the Nvidia drivers many times to no avail. How can I fix this issue or even figure out what is causing it?

Edit:

Laptop Info
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ
Graphics: Nvidia GTX1060
Driver: NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.20
OS type: 64 bit

Comment: Try using the Skylake driver http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-hd-530&num=1

Answer (score 1):

With your Intel Skylake processor others have reported freezing when an external monitor was connected. Some found upgrading to kernel 4.4.25 solved that problem. However since this kernel version is outdated the current version 4.4.33 would be a better.

To install 4.4.33, use:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.33/linux-headers-4.4.33-040433_4.4.33-040433.201611180742_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.33/linux-headers-4.4.33-040433-generic_4.4.33-040433.201611180742_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.33/linux-image-4.4.33-040433-generic_4.4.33-040433.201611180742_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo reboot
```

To improve your question you can list your Nvidia card model number, ie GTX 1060 and Nvidia driver in use, ie 367.57. Also where you obtained the driver, ie `System Settings` -> `Software & Upgrades` -> `Additional Drivers` or Nvidia ppa, etc.

The more information you provide, the better chances of success.

#### Edit 1 - Try Intel only settings

Isolate if it's a Nvidia problem or Intel system problem by turning off Nvidia and using Intel graphcis. Run Nvidia's X Server Settings from Dash or the terminal by typing `nvidia-settings`.

Change your settings like so:

[image: Nvidia Settings]

Save, Quit and reboot.

If the external monitor doesn't work on reboot we need to focus on Intel microcode, driver configuration, etc. If the external monitor works on reboot we need to focus on Nvidia Driver 375, X-Org serttings, etc.

Comment: I successfully updated the firmware. Now when I plug in the HDMI cord the laptop screen goes on and off but the external monitor remains undetected. I have added some system details to the original post.

Comment: From command line can you type: `sudo prime-select intel`?

Comment: PRIME Profiles is not an option on my nvidia settings. Trying to use sudo prime-select intel results in the following:   

`Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', None]  
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', None]  
Error: the installed packages do not support PRIME  
Error: intel mode can't be enabled`

Comment: Sorry I couldnt format that comment above any better. There are the results of running **sudo prime-select intel**.

Comment: If Kernel 4.4.33 doesn't work for you, you can try 4.8.5 as detailed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/850470/how-can-i-debug-frequent-unrecoverable-freezes/850816?noredirect=1#comment1309473_850816