# Random freezing and crashes on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, crash

I'm experiencing very frequent complete system freezes on Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell 7559 with Intel and Nvidia 960m.

I've tried adding a line to grub found in a previous solution but it didn't work. The problem just started today after no previous issues. It began while using Firefox and then persisted while using Chrome. Also freezes while using other programs, such as WPS Office.

Here's some recent /var/log info from during the most recent freeze. Only way to get system working again seems to be a forced restart.

As I was writing this it also did an unexpected restart.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers

```
   Feb  7 17:28:20 danbook systemd[1263]: Reached target Paths.
Feb  7 17:28:20 danbook systemd[1263]: Reached target Timers.
Feb  7 17:28:20 danbook systemd[1263]: Reached target Sockets.
Feb  7 17:28:20 danbook systemd[1263]: Reached target Basic System.
Feb  7 17:28:20 danbook systemd[1263]: Reached target Default.
Feb  7 17:28:20 danbook systemd[1263]: Startup finished in 11ms.
Feb  7 17:28:20 danbook systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 108.
Feb  7 17:28:20 danbook org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1285]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook org.gnome.ScreenSaver[1277]: ** (gnome-screensaver:1347): WARNING **: Couldn't get presence status: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /org/gnome/SessionManager/Presence
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook org.gnome.ScreenSaver[1277]: ** (gnome-screensaver:1347): WARNING **: screensaver already running in this session
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook ModemManager[1048]: <info>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:04:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook ModemManager[1048]: <info>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:05:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service'
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook systemd[1]: Starting RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service...
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1'
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook systemd[1]: Started RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Successfully called chroot.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Successfully dropped privileges.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Successfully limited resources.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Running.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Watchdog thread running.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Canary thread running.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Successfully made thread 1376 of process 1376 (n/a) owned by '108' high priority at nice level -11.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' unit='upower.service'
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook systemd[1]: Starting Daemon for power management...
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Successfully made thread 1398 of process 1376 (n/a) owned by '108' RT at priority 5.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Successfully made thread 1400 of process 1376 (n/a) owned by '108' RT at priority 5.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook bluetoothd[1046]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook bluetoothd[1046]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook pulseaudio[1376]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Successfully made thread 1403 of process 1403 (n/a) owned by '108' high priority at nice level -11.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook pulseaudio[1403]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook kernel: [   11.539247] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook kernel: [   11.539251] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Feb  7 17:28:21 danbook kernel: [   11.539255] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Feb  7 17:28:22 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower'
Feb  7 17:28:22 danbook systemd[1]: Started Daemon for power management.
Feb  7 17:28:22 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service'
Feb  7 17:28:22 danbook systemd[1]: Starting Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Feb  7 17:28:22 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.ColorManager'
Feb  7 17:28:22 danbook systemd[1]: Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5255] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5293] policy: auto-activating connection 'EWEPEM'
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5300] device (wlp5s0): Activation: starting connection 'EWEPEM' (ef1187b9-76e3-45cb-95f9-d6216e558eb1)
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5300] device (wlp5s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5301] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5304] device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5305] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'EWEPEM' has security, but secrets are required.
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5305] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook whoopsie[1002]: [17:28:23] offline
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5327] device (wlp5s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5329] device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5330] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'EWEPEM' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5331] Config: added 'ssid' value 'EWEPEM'
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5331] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5331] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5331] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5331] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5399] sup-iface[0x1ac0590,wlp5s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with a4:2b:b0:e0:c7:6e (SSID='EWEPEM' freq=2412 MHz)
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook kernel: [   13.123822] wlp5s0: authenticate with a4:2b:b0:e0:c7:6e
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5521] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook kernel: [   13.128525] wlp5s0: send auth to a4:2b:b0:e0:c7:6e (try 1/3)
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp5s0: Trying to associate with a4:2b:b0:e0:c7:6e (SSID='EWEPEM' freq=2412 MHz)
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook kernel: [   13.130392] wlp5s0: authenticated
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook kernel: [   13.133896] wlp5s0: associate with a4:2b:b0:e0:c7:6e (try 1/3)
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5587] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook kernel: [   13.137776] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from a4:2b:b0:e0:c7:6e (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp5s0: Associated with a4:2b:b0:e0:c7:6e
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook kernel: [   13.138212] wlp5s0: associated
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook kernel: [   13.138235] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
Feb  7 17:28:23 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463303.5666] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1277]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of dan.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook systemd[1]: Started Session c2 of user dan.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook systemd[1450]: Reached target Timers.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook systemd[1450]: Reached target Sockets.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook systemd[1450]: Reached target Paths.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook systemd[1450]: Reached target Basic System.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook systemd[1450]: Reached target Default.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook systemd[1450]: Startup finished in 10ms.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.6312] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with a4:2b:b0:e0:c7:6e [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook wpa_supplicant[1237]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to a4:2b:b0:e0:c7:6e completed [id=0 id_str=]
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.6593] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.6593] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'EWEPEM'.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.6594] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.6627] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.6811] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): dhclient started with pid 1512
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook dhclient[1512]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.100 on wlp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7d346fd1)
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook dhclient[1512]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.100 from 192.168.1.1
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7828]   address 192.168.1.100
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7828]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7828]   gateway 192.168.1.1
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7828]   server identifier 192.168.1.1
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7828]   lease time 259200
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7828]   hostname 'dhcppc0'
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7828]   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7828] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook avahi-daemon[936]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp5s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.100.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook avahi-daemon[936]: New relevant interface wlp5s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook avahi-daemon[936]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.100 on wlp5s0.IPv4.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7837] device (wlp5s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7841] device (wlp5s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7846] device (wlp5s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.7847] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook dhclient[1512]: bound to 192.168.1.100 -- renewal in 118825 seconds.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.8037] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.8038] policy: set 'EWEPEM' (wlp5s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.8038] dns-plugin[0x1a854a0]: starting dnsmasq...
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook whoopsie[1002]: [17:28:24] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.8130] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook dnsmasq[1537]: started, version 2.75 cache disabled
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook dnsmasq[1537]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook dnsmasq[1537]: DBus support enabled: connected to system bus
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook dnsmasq[1537]: warning: no upstream servers configured
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.9850] device (wlp5s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [wlp5s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [wlp5s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463304.9865] dnsmasq[0x1a854a0]: dnsmasq appeared as :1.67
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook dnsmasq[1537]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook dnsmasq[1537]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook whoopsie[1002]: [17:28:24] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook whoopsie[1002]: [17:28:24] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
Feb  7 17:28:24 danbook whoopsie[1002]: [17:28:24] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook whoopsie[1002]: [17:28:25] online
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463305.4302] manager: startup complete
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Wait Online.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 4h 25min 51.701681s random time.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 4h 38min 186.026ms random time.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Starting Set console scheme...
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Reached target Login Prompts.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Started Set console scheme.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook virtualbox[1826]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook kernel: [   15.176610] vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook kernel: [   15.194246] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 2592002857 Hz
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook kernel: [   15.194248] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.0.32_Ubuntu (interface 0x00240000)
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook kernel: [   15.222703] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook kernel: [   15.234485] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook kernel: [   15.244029] VBoxPciLinuxInit
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook virtualbox[1826]:    ...done.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Started LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook kernel: [   15.258160] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook systemd[1]: Startup finished in 2.150s (kernel) + 13.124s (userspace) = 33.302s.
Feb  7 17:28:25 danbook org.ayatana.bamf[1731]: bamfdaemon start/running, process 1887
Feb  7 17:28:26 danbook avahi-daemon[936]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp5s0.IPv6 with address fe80::5d0d:e692:294f:3eee.
Feb  7 17:28:26 danbook avahi-daemon[936]: New relevant interface wlp5s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Feb  7 17:28:26 danbook avahi-daemon[936]: Registering new address record for fe80::5d0d:e692:294f:3eee on wlp5s0.*.
Feb  7 17:28:26 danbook org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1925]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Successfully made thread 2021 of process 2021 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook org.gnome.ScreenSaver[1731]: ** (gnome-screensaver:1951): WARNING **: Couldn't get presence status: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Successfully made thread 2042 of process 2021 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Successfully made thread 2043 of process 2021 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook rtkit-daemon[1377]: Supervising 6 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook bluetoothd[1046]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook bluetoothd[1046]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook pulseaudio[2021]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook bluetoothd[1046]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook gnome-session[1915]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook gnome-session[1915]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Feb  7 17:28:27 danbook gnome-session[1915]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service'
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook gnome-session[1915]: (process:2065): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: Unable to get watcher name 'org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher'
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook gnome-session[1915]: (process:2065): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: Name Lost
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook gnome-session-binary[1915]: Entering running state
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook systemd[1]: Starting Locale Service...
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook gnome-session[1915]: ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook gnome-session[1915]: ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks2' unit='udisks2.service'
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook systemd[1]: Started Locale Service.
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook udisksd[2100]: udisks daemon version 2.1.7 starting
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2'
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook udisksd[2100]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor[1731]: Volume monitor alive
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook gnome-session[1915]: (gnome-software:2076): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook gnome-session[1915]: (gnome-software:2076): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' (using servicehelper)
Feb  7 17:28:28 danbook gnome-session[1915]: Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28
Feb  7 17:28:29 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463309.4301] WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Feb  7 17:28:29 danbook NetworkManager[1056]: <info>  [1486463309.4301] WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Feb  7 17:28:29 danbook dbus[938]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Feb  7 17:28:30 danbook org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1731]: ** (process:2157): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/1 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
Feb  7 17:28:30 danbook org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1731]: message repeated 2 times: [ ** (process:2157): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/1 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)]
Feb  7 17:28:30 danbook org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1731]: ** (process:2157): WARNING **: send_done_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/1 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
Feb  7 17:28:30 danbook org.gnome.ScreenSaver[1731]: ** Message: Lost the name, shutting down.
Feb  7 17:28:30 danbook gnome-session[1915]: PluginRegistry::load_plugins: Importing plugin __init__.py failed: 'module' object has no attribute 'AVAILABLE'
Feb  7 17:28:44 danbook bluetoothd[1046]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Feb  7 17:28:44 danbook bluetoothd[1046]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Feb  7 17:28:45 danbook systemd-timesyncd[845]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Feb  7 17:28:48 danbook org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[1731]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:2372): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:229: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
Feb  7 17:29:11 danbook systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
Feb  7 17:29:11 danbook systemd[1]: Stopped Read required files in advance.
Feb  7 17:29:11 danbook systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
```

Comment: Instead of restarting you may be able to unlock a frozen session by swapping to TTY1 with ALT-CTRL+ F1, and then swapping back to Unity on TTY7 with ATL-CTRL + F7. I've had these issues continually with Nvidia on Ubuntu 16.04 (14.04) on two different systems with two different video cards. I would love to get to the bottom of where  this bug lies. Does this work around work in your system?

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go. The freezing has been so frequent that even this would be annoying. Not done it for a little while now but I'll post back when it happens again if this works. What I don't understand is what prompted this. I've been using the maching for over a month with the same setup and have had no problems. No major software changes. Only difference is I recently switched to using Firefox from Chrome. I'm stumped.

Comment: This doesn't work as the keyboard is frozen as well. Can't do anything. Sometimes long periods are OK then it will crash every few minutes if a browser is open. Testing for bad blocks and have restored /home but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

could be linked to this kernel issue: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051

the following solution from this thread solved it for me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/852080

Disable `intel_cstates` (power saving states meant to reduce CPU waste heat and power usage) by editing `/etc/default/grub`:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Find the line containing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Add `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` directly following `splash`.

Alternatively, if your BIOS supports doing so, disable said C-states from there.

**Note: this is** *not* **a long-term fix. Disabling C-states heavily increases power-draw and waste heat. Only try this if there are no other solutions and updating your kernel does not solve anything!**

Answer (score 0):

This could be a hardware issue. I guess your hard disk is sick. You can verify by running a live Ubuntu 16.04 session. Try to recreate the issue in the live session, if you see the same freeze/lag, then it will prove my assumption wrong and you should be able to fix the issue with a reinstall. But if your live session runs smoothly then there are high chances that your hard disk is failing. I am saying this because I can't see anything unusual in your /var/log.

Once my friend's laptop had similar issue, initially his os was freezing and after a few days it stopped even booting. I verified hard disk failure with a live ubuntu session and concluded to replace the hard disk.

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. If you have a new question please [ask it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I have provided a workaround, though not the best answer but it might help.