# Any way to verify the completeness of texlive-full installation on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, latex, texlive

I'm new to linux, and I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop.

I installed texlive-full with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Since the total size of the packages was quite large (>3 GB) and the ETA was >1.5 hrs, I'd left the installation for itself. I returned to find that the system had frozen midway. I forcefully shut down my system by holding down the power button and restarted the installation process by running the command again. This time, it froze after the installation was complete. During the 2nd installation attempt, there were two packages whose download had stopped, but the installation had skipped over them to continue with other packages. I know this because I was present in front of the screen before leaving the installation for itself.

My questions are two fold:

1. Is there any way to check whether texlive-full was installed fully and correctly? Maybe some command that compares the online repository with the one on the system? Or is there any place where the installation process creates a log file that I can read and see what packages were installed? I want to see the text that the system prints on the screen while installing the packages or some log of the installation process or list of the missing packages so that instead of running `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` again, I could install only those specific packages.
2. Why did the system freeze on both the occasions? Have any of you faced this issue with 16.04? How can I avoid that in future if I install such large packages?

Any ideas or suggestions will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I know it's not an answer to anything you ask but is there a special reason why you want the full install? Usually it is better install texlive and than let itself install packages when needed..

Comment: @derHugo I installed the full version to not be bothered with installing the necessary packages later. I could of course install the texlive like you said, and install the necessary packages when needed. But even if you take this as a hypothetical scenario, where you have to install a program that downloads a lot of packages, how would you go about verifying that every package has indeed been downloaded and installed correctly? Say, Matlab for instance, or some other program with a lot of packages. Surely there must be a better way than to try to run the program and see whether it crashes?

Comment: The second question has already been asked by several others at the link below - https://askubuntu.com/questions/850470/how-can-i-debug-frequent-unrecoverable-freezes