# 16.04.2 delayed again?

Tags: 16.04

the question may be a little impatient... but february 9th is over in every timezone; and this is the announced [release date for 16.04.2](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule).

but on the [official download page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/) 16.04.02 is not (yet) available.

has there been an announcement of an additional delay? or is it just my impatience that is getting the better of me?

**UPDATE** (`Tue Feb 14 11:42:15 UTC 2017`; i.e. feb 14 in all timezones)

as stated by answers below:

```
$ lsb_release -av
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

an installed system will update itself to `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS` but there are still no `.iso`s on the [official download page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/).

the status on the [qa site](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/372/builds) does not look promising yet...

---

**UPDATE** (`Fri Feb 17 2017 11:00:00 UTC`)

Updated ISO files have finally been [released](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2017-February/004036.html). You can now [download the `.iso` files](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/) for both desktop and server editions.

Comment: I would leave it up for a few days and then close it, in case others look for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Edit :

Ubuntu 16.04.2 will not automatically install newer kernel and X.org stack by default. Switching to Hardware Enablement Stack is optional.

To install 16.04.2 HWE Stack, run

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

Also, updated ISOs are now available.

[Source1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882896/old-kernel-with-ubuntu-16-04-2-update), [Source2](http://www.cnx-software.com/2017/02/13/how-to-upgrade-to-linux-4-8-in-ubuntu-16-04-2/)

Here is the [change summary](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/16.04.2).

---

### **I actually have 16.04.2 right now! (But updated ISOs are not available yet)**

Ubuntu 16.04.2 has been [delayed till Monday](http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-17-04-alpha-1-released-for-opt-in-flavors-ships-with-linux-kernel-4-9-511397.shtml). Read [more about it](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-16.04.2-LTS-LM-Delay).

Local time & date in India as of this writing : 8:30 PM, Feb 10th.

I installed Ubuntu 16.10's kernel on Ubuntu 16.04.1 about a week ago. [See this for more info.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836260/how-can-i-use-16-10-yakkety-kernel-in-16-04-xenial)

Yesterday(9th Feb) I got the Mesa 12.0.6 ( [planned for 16.04.2](http://news.softpedia.com/news/turns-out-ubuntu-16-04-2-is-shipping-with-mesa-12-0-6-here-s-how-to-use-mesa-13-512756.shtml) ) and `linux-firmware 1.157.8` updates through update manager.

Now my `lsb_release -a` output says that I have Ubuntu 16.04.2.

Proof:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks! could you add the phoronix and softpedia links from your comments? you were the first to point these out; then i could accept your answer.

Comment: Can i use this command to upgrade 14.04 to 16.04.2?

Answer (score 3):

## Indeed!

Yes, there was a last minute delay.

Source: http://phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-16.04.2-LTS-LM-Delay

Hope this helps