# Upgrade 16.04.2 LTS to kernel version 4.8?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, lts, aptitude

I am on `Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-62-generic i686)` and when I do:

```
aptitude update
aptitude safe-upgrade
```

no upgrades are offered. `aptitude search linux-headers-4.8` offers several 4.8 kernels:

```
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-28                                                        - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.8.0
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-28-generic                                                - Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-28-lowlatency                                             - Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-30                                                        - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.8.0
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-30-generic                                                - Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-30-lowlatency                                             - Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-32                                                        - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.8.0
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-32-generic                                                - Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-32-lowlatency                                             - Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-34                                                        - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.8.0
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-34-generic                                                - Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-34-lowlatency                                             - Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-36                                                        - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.8.0
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic                                                - Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
p   linux-headers-4.8.0-36-lowlatency                                             - Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
```

In the German Wikipedia under `ubuntu` is written that the kernel 4.8 is available for 16.04.2 LTS since 17 February 2017:

[image]

The English Wikipedia and [the Ubuntu release page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) is still on kernel version 4.4 for 16.04.2 LTS. The later one (Ubuntu release page) omits 16.04.2 LTS also and seems to be not up-to-date.

Is it a little bit too early or should I update the kernel by hand?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04.2 installs a 4.8 kernel for *new installations*. For systems which are upgraded to 16.04.2 the current kernel series is maintained unchanged. If you have upgraded your system to 16.04.2 and want to have the new kernel and X server, then you must opt in by explicitly installing the [hardware enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

This switches the kernel and X server to a rolling upgrade; see [RollingLTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack) .

Also see [Old kernel with Ubuntu 16.04.2 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882896/old-kernel-with-ubuntu-16-04-2-update), as user Pilot6 says.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the advantage of `aptitude install linux-generic-hwe-16.04` over `aptitude install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04`?

Comment: @musbach: The first enrolls only the kernel in the HWE; the second enrolls both the kernel and the X server. If you do not have a pressing need for a new kernel and/or a new X server you should keep the current series, however. The kernel and X server series available initially in 16.04 will be supported for the entire life of 16.04.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I have installed the x-server on kernel 4.4. But are there two different versions of the x-server for kernel 4.8?

Comment: @musbach: They are different software products, not linked to one another.

Comment: .. and you recomment the new software? Is the old one deinstalled?

Comment: @musbach: The new version(s) may have support for new hardware. If your hardware is already supported there is no reason whatsoever to move to a new kernel series.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53902/discussion-between-musbach-and-alexp).

Comment: Does this defeat the purpose of an LTS?

Comment: Shouldn´t it be --with-recommends?

Comment: @flohack: My `apt-get` understands `--install-recommends` and does not understand `--with-recommends`. Is the option `--with-recommends` documented anywhere?