# Weird glitch screen XPS 13

Tags: google-chrome, dell, screen, gpu-driver

On my brand new Dell XPS 13 9360 Developer edition, there is a glitch on my screen. I might be chrome specific, but I'm unsure.

There are only a couple of lines of and moving the mouse through them typically clears the glitch.

I've already disable hardware acceleration for Chrome (which was causing flickering), but this issue remains.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: We have a few of these models at work. We haven't had that issue. But we wipe and install a clean 16.04.2 as soon as it arrives. I personally don't want anything Dell installed.   So, if a clean install is an option, maybe give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the shipped Ubuntu the HWE packs for the Kernel and X aren't installed. When doing a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04.02, the are automatically installed.

Installing the HWE packs, will install a newer version of the Linux kernel (4.8.0). This new kernel solved these glitches.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

*See [https://askubuntu.com/questions/882896/old-kernel-with-ubuntu-16-04-2-update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882896/old-kernel-with-ubuntu-16-04-2-update_)*