# Ubuntu 16.04 ethernet doesnt work automatically

Tags: ethernet

to begin with im gonna say that I am a total noob and its my first experience with ubuntu, I just want to see all the pros and cons of it. My problem is that even though my internet cable is connected to my pc, I dont get internet connection automatically. Ive been searching on the internet and I found these two commands :

sudo modprobe alx

echo '1969 e0b1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/alx/new_id

They do help and I get internet connection immediately after using them, but my question is if there is any permanent fix to my problem? These commands only fix the problem until i reboot my pc, then it comes back again. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The alias for your device, 1969:e0b1, we assume, was added to the *alx* driver beginning in the 4.8.0-xx kernel version. If *alx* doesn't drive your device, that suggests that you are running an earlier kernel version than 4.8. Confirm:

```
uname -r
```

There are three ways you can get the driver to load and drive your device automatically. First, upgrade to a 4.8 kernel as described here: [Old kernel with Ubuntu 16.04.2 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882896/old-kernel-with-ubuntu-16-04-2-update)

Second, you can download and install Ubuntu 17.04, the latest release. It uses kernel version 4.10 and *alx* contains the alias for your device.

Third, if you are unable to do either, make an edit to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Right above the exit 0 line, add:

```
modprobe alx
echo '1969 e0b1' > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/alx/new_id
```

Note that sudo is not required or even possible in rc.local. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

You should be all set.